# CodeLite Debugger doesn't open files

Tags: fopen, codelite

My linux executable works fine when I run it directly or using gdb

but when I'm using codelite, at this statement

fp = fopen("../../../../../data/data.csv", "r");

it returns NULL for fp,
looks like CodeLite cannot figure out where the file is,

Do I need to set some kind of an environmental variable ?

Comment: I use codelite 13 and the project is built using a make file without the involvement of codelite. I just use the quick debug option in codelite and provide it the executable to extract the sources

Answer (score 1):

Just set the working directory to the same directory where you have the executable